# XPath NodeSet in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodesets

I have this code in eclipse

```
NodeSet nodes = (NodeSet) xPath.evaluate(expression,inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

and its giving me compile time error on NodeSet.

These are the stuff that I have imported. Can you tell me why it's doing this?

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As indicated NodeSet is not part of the standard libraries. However, from the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html#NODESET), NodeSet maps to a NodeList, so you could just use that instead. So it would become:

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression,inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

You would have to import `org.w3c.dom.NodeList`.